# Host Azure website application to another domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Currently my application url is `xyz.azurewebsites.net`. I have to host that application to another domain like `www.xyz.com`. I have company's domain and I have to host from `xyz.azurewebsite.net` to company's domain.

I don't know how to host from azurewebsite.net to another domain.

Please suggest me proper steps.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the Azure documentation: WebApps > Manage > Custom Domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you [configure a custom domain name](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/) for your web site. Since you already have company's domain as the custom domian. You just need to do below two basic steps:

1.Create DNS records that map the domain to your Azure web app.

2.Add the domain name inside the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

Note: Setting a custom domain name is only available for the **Shared**, **Basic** and **Standard** modes for Web Apps. Before switching a web app from the **Free** mode to the **Shared**, **Basic** or **Standard** mode, you must first remove spending caps in place for your Web Apps subscription.

For detailed information, please refer to [this MS article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).